# Scraping data from a site where javascript param is not given through URL

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from http://spinning.com/find-a-class.  The problem is when I change the Zip and radius the URL doesn't change.  I'm not sure how to make it so that I can open the webpage to a specific Zip to be scraped.

I'm wondering how I can get the site to open and already have a specific zip specified.  I am scraping in python.  I'm not familiar with javascript so I'm not sure how to proceed.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Monitoring the network request shows it's calling this API:

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.bullseyelocations.com/pages/MDDGTEST?f=1'
rs = requests.post(url, data={
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hfTotalPages': 1,
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hfResultsPerPage': 20,
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCityStateZip': 'New York, NY',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hfCountry': 'United States',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$radiusList': 5})
```